# Elasticsearch create doc with custom _id

Tags: elasticsearch

is there any way to create document without indicating the _id in the URL? I understand that there is option to create document using  http://localhost:9200/[index_name]/[index_type]/[_id], I do have issues creating a document using this option as my _id is not auto-generated and the _id might have special characters such as # or &. I am currently using elasticsearch version 1.3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to create documents without having to add the URL-encoded ID in the URL is to use the [`_bulk` API](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-bulk.html). It simply goes like this:

```
POST index/doc/_bulk
{"index": {"_id": "1234#5678"}}
{"field": "value", "number": 34}
{"index": {"_id": "5555#7896"}}
{"field": "another", "number": 45}
```

As you can see, you can index several documents and their IDs is simply given within quotes inside the body of the bulk request. The URL itself simply invokes the `_bulk` endpoint.

Comment: I couldn't execute the above example in Sense. it says "ActionRequestValidationException[Validation Failed: 1: no requests added;]".. I have actually put it line by line

Comment: Make sure to add a new line after the document (it doesn't show up in my answer)

Comment: I make a mistake while executing the above example in Sense. I replaced the word "index" with my index name. My mistake. Actually I can also use this _bulk for the update right?

Comment: Yes, you can use `_bulk` for any CRUD operation: create, index, delete, update. Check in the official documentation, as there is such an example